# Table Tag Not Nesting Inside P Tags In DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have been playin with dynamic changes to innerHTML content and have noticed some strange behaviour with tables nested inside other elements.

For example form p /p p table /table /p /form was not seeing the table as innerHTML of the second p but instead listed the table as a sibling of that p tag rather than a child.

I figure this is a well known behaviour.

What is the gap in my knowlegde?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put a `<table>` inside a `<p>`. From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> `<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->`
>   [...]
>    It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

And then if you look at what the [`%inline;` elements are](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline), you won't find `<table>` in the list.

And for HTML5, [`<p>` can contain *phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html):

> **Permitted contents**
>
> Phrasing content

And [*phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) is character data and [*phrasing elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing), *phrasing elements* are:

> *a* or *em* or *strong* or *small* ... *meter*

There's no `<table>` in that list.

So you're trying to insert invalid HTML and the browser is changing `<p><table></table></p>` into `<p></p><table></table>` (i.e. moving the table child up to a sibling) in order to get valid HTML.

If you give the browser invalid HTML, the browser will guess what you really mean and go with its guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both `<p>` and `<table>` are block-level elements.

Use a container element for your table, like a `<div>`.

Good luck! :)