# Hide not working when table is present

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, hide

I've got a website which has a table with lots of data in it, in the head of the page I have the following code: -

```
$(function() {
$("td[colspan=3]").find("P").hide();
});
```

And when my main table has a `<P> test </P>` in there it correctly hides this (I have a button which then shows this and I know that works).

However, if I enter a sub table into that table between the P's like so

```
<td colspan="3">
    <P>
        <table>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
        </table>
    </P>
</td>
```

The table is not hidden...  What am I missing?  I also tried

```
$("td[colspan=3]").find("P").find("table").hide();
```

But no dice here either...

Comment: Give an "Id" to that "td".

Comment: @Praveen not sure what you mean by adding an ID to the td, which td?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is cause because you have an invalide HTML.

The `<p>` tag cannot contain an other block inside, it is a text tag with the properties of a block. Once the broswer run hover a block tag inside the `<p>`, it close automaticly the `<p>` and opan the new tag.

If you inspect the dom here : http://jsfiddle.net/pqJTZ/, you'll see the `<p>` is empty.

The solution is to use a `<div>` instead.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459652/table-tag-not-nesting-inside-p-tags-in-dom) give you good links and a proper explanation.

Comment: this is right!
if you still want to hide table:
... .find("p").next("table").hide();

Comment: This is right, and here the fiddle with a div instead of a p http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/6qS4w/

Comment: Both reyaner and karls solutions work, thanks very much for giving me a plethora of options to work from! :)