# Weird issue with PHP and html markup

Tags: php, html, string

I have a weird issue with my html codes.

I want to add the a variable `$htmlstring` to a `<p>` tag.

I do

```
 $finalHtml .= '<p class="text">'.$htmlString.'</p>';
```

My `$htmlstring` contains something like

```
<span>texts….</span>
<span>texts….</span>
<span>texts….</span>
<span>texts….</span>
<span>texts….</span>

<table>
    <tr>
       <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
     </tr>
    more….
</table>

<span>more texts</span>
<span>more texts</span>
```

I want my result to become like

```
<p class='text'>
     <span>texts….</span>
    <span>texts….</span>
    <span>texts….</span>
    <span>texts….</span>
   <span>texts….</span>

   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
       <td>cell</td>
       <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      more….
   </table>
   <span>more texts</span>
   <span>more texts</span>
</p>
```

but i got

```
//p tag only wraps texts before my table element.
<p class='text'>
     <span>texts….</span>
    <span>texts….</span>
    <span>texts….</span>
    <span>texts….</span>
   <span>texts….</span>
</p>

   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
       <td>cell</td>
       <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      more….
   </table>
   <span>more texts</span>
   <span>more texts</span>
```

can anyone help me with this weird issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `<p>` cannot contain a `<table>`, that isn't valid HTML.

Comment: check this out: [table-tag-not-nesting-inside-p-tags-in-dom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459652/table-tag-not-nesting-inside-p-tags-in-dom)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the raw output of the php, before the browser interprets it? I suspect your `p` end tag appears where you wanted it, but the browser reinterpreted the page.

Comment: $finalHtml .= "<div class=\"text\">${htmlString}</div>";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `p` can't hold a `block` element (`table`).

Use a `div` instead of your `p`aragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your code through the validator?

the validator would have told you that you cannot put

```
 <p> <table> ...
```

or

```
<table> <p>
```

check out:
http://validator.w3.org/